# CMS upload picture files security issue

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I have a quick question if anyone could help.  I am building a CMS for a client where they can log in, and change content (including pictures via upload file form) that are all stored in a database.

My question.. I have been researching, and everywhere says I need to store the image files outside the root folder.  Is this necessary in my case if only a few people will be uploading files, inside an admin panel, where they must first log in to the site?  I will have already taken steps client side by making sure of file type, size, extension etc... then changing the name of the file before adding it to my DB... Is this secure enough, or am I asking for trouble down the road?

Thanks

Comment: If the images are indented for admin-only viewing, then yes, it must be located in a secure folder (outside the web dir, or secured by htaccess). If the images will be shown on the main site (if there's one) it **should** be public.

Comment: If you are making a file browser, you may want a directory for only uploaded files. But it can be inside your web root without problems.  You aren't trying to restrict access to the files, right?

Comment: the pics will be viewed on the main website, yes. if I put them inside the root, it won't open the site up for uploaded phishing scripts, virus, etc?

Comment: What happens if one of those "few people" have their account information stolen? maybe they use the same login and password for multiple sites, other site gets compromised, your site is now compromised. then whoever has the credentials can login and upload anything to the admin panel. And you can't rely on anything client side as far as validation. It is nothing but a convenience for the user so they don't have to load another page before seeing an error. You MUST also check in PHP when handling the upload. The only way to be SURE, is put images somewhere the webserver wont run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its generally a good idea to store uploaded content someplace where it cant directly be addressed by a browser.  You dont want someone uploading a .php file (or some other format you forgot to check for) and then being able execute it by pulling up the direct url.  Rather, you'd have a wrapper script that delivered the file.

So yes, its a good idea, but not 'necessary' (by the dictionary definition of the word).  You can certainly choose *not* to do so if in your judgement the admin area is otherwise secure.

That said, in the scenario you describe, as long as its only admin users who can upload images, I dont think its a huge deal either way.

btw, if you are not already, verify the images by their file headers or content, not file extension.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll store it outside just to be safe. Although I'm sure there is a way to get attacked this way too, it would be a lot harder.